# Mips x32 using an array

Tags: assembly, mips, mips32

im writing this code for one of my assignments and i need to have an array of size 128 which i do by

```
drops: .space 128
```

so that i can load that specific spot in drops and store a number 0-8 to it.....

for example.... say the random number was 32 and i was on the first iteration of the loop 
it would store 0 in the 32nd spot of the array
if i was in the 2 iteration of the array... it would store 1 in the random number eg 92..spot

here is my code:

I first made everything in my array -1 so that i can test to see if something was in it...

```
storeArray: 

 la $t6, drops
 la $t1, 0  #counter


loopStoreRandom:

    move $a0, $s5   # send x 
    jal getDrop
    move $t2, $v0 #t2 has a random number 

    add $t6, $t6, $t2  #random + the whole   ---wrong

    lb $t3, ($t6)       
    bne $t3, -1, loopStoreRandom


    addi $t1, $t1, 1
    beq $t1, 128, exit
    j loopStoreRandom
```

so as you see i wish there was something that i could to just be like `sb $t1, $t2($t6)` but i can't

Comment: Why can't that work?  Is there an assembly error?  A proscription against using an instruction?  What?

Comment: idk it just don't work... whenever i test it ... when i go to exit la $t6, drops
lb $t5, 32($t6)

move $a0, $t5
li $v0, 1
syscall
li $v0, 10
syscall
and it will print out a -1 .... it should print out a number 0 -8

Comment: im sorry it actually doesn't even return any number

Answer (score 0):

Your're not restoring $t6 each loop, so the pointer becomes off after the first loop.

Move

```
la $t6, drops
```

inside the loop.

Comment: I did that... and its still comming back as -1 when it should be a number thats either 0-8

Comment: Well, I can 't see that you are storing anything to the array, so ofcourse it will return -1 if you previously initialized all entries to that.

Answer (score 0):

```
jal getDrop
move $t2, $v0 #t2 has a random number
```

Assuming v0 is returned from getDrop, the move instruction will  be executed BEORE getDrop is executed as it will execute as part of jal's delay slot. So T2 is not going to contain the returned value of getDrop.

should be:

```
jal getDrop
nop

move $t2, $v0
```

Comment: That depends on the execution environment. SPIM by deafult does not simulate branch delay slots. The same probably applies for MARS.

Comment: I was beginning to suspect that after seeing lots of other MIPs examples around here doing the same thing.